# access xml element by attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

Probably this question repeated, but i am not satiesfied with existing answers. I want to get xml element from dynamically generated xml file by attribute value. we don't know how many nodes, and its herarchy. but each element, its sub element, its sub-sub elements, sub-sub-sub elements...so on will contain unique guid as "Id" attribute :

```
    <Element id="">
  <SubElement id=""></SubElement>
  <SubElement id="">
    <SubSubElement id="">
      <SubSubSubElement id="">
        <SubSubSubSubElement id="">....other sub inside this ...</SubSubSubSubElement>
      </SubSubSubElement>
    </SubSubElement>
  </SubElement>
</Element>
```

I want to find the element by only passing the Guid value. nonethless of its xpath, its node location / position. how can i do this in C#? is i need to use LINQ?

**Edited:**

```
 XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
XElement selectedElement = xmldoc.Descendants().Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("id") == myIdvalue).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Exception :**
"Expression cannot contain lambda expressions"
I have added Using System.Linq namspaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

hoipolloi has given an XPath answer, which is fine - but I would personally use LINQ to XML. (See [my blog post on code and data for reasons](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/code-and-data/).)

```
var element = parent.Descendants()
                    .Where(x => (Guid?) x.Attribute("id") == id)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will perform appropriate GUID parsing on each `id` attribute (returning a "null" `Guid?` value for non-GUIDs). If you're certain of the text format of your ID, you can cast to string instead:

```
var element = parent.Descendants()
                    .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("id") == idText)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Change the `FirstOrDefault` to `Single`, `SingleOrDefault` or `First` depending on your requirements.

EDIT: It's not at all clear what's going wrong with the code you've posted. Here's a short but complete program which shows it working fine. Please compare this with your code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string xml = "<parent><foo id='bar' /><foo id='baz' /></parent>";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        string idToFind = "bar";
        XElement selectedElement = doc.Descendants()
            .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("id") == idToFind).FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(selectedElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the advantages of using LINQ? I haven't developed in C# since .NET 1.2. FYI, I've just bought your book to bring myself up to speed with 4. :)

Comment: @hoipolloi: I find it helps to keep the *data* parts away from the *code* parts - the compiler can detect syntax errors at compile-time, you know that the methods (`Descendants` etc) will really be there - all that's deferred until execution time are the genuine data-dependent aspects. LINQ to XML also makes namespace handling a breeze :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I already tried these expressions but i am getting "Expression cannot contain lambda expressions". If i am right then "Parent" must be the XDocument object loaded with xml document. why should i am getting this exception?

Comment: @Red Swan: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It should be fine.

Comment: @Red Swan: Your code tries to cast to `string?` which is an invalid type - you can only use `?` as a suffix for non-nullable value types.

Comment: umm... i changed that and tried again. but still not accepting lambda expression.

Comment: @Red Swan: It compiles perfectly for me. Do you have `using System.Linq;` in your using directives? Please post the exact error message in your question.

Comment: Yes Jon Skeet, i have added my exception in question. in fact till, i am not using lambda expression, it works fine. but as soon i trying lambda expression it is showing me this exception.

Comment: @Red Swan: I've added a short but complete program which compiles and runs without error. Are you trying to do something funky like running this as part of a LINQ to SQL query?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I am getting this at execution time, in immediate window.

Comment: @Red Swan: Then don't run it in the immediate window! Put it as part of a real program. It sounds like the immediate window doesn't support lambda expressions. In future *please* mention things like "I'm trying to run it in the immediate window" when you have problems - it changes things completely.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks John Skeet, its working in real code perfectly. i think i am habitual with immediate window :) i will strictly remember next time. Nice to brainstorming with you. Thanks champ.

Comment: @Red Swan: Cool. Do you think the code in my edit is still useful, or shall I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use XPath to do this. For instance, the following matches all elements with an id of 'foo', irrespective of their location in the document:

```
//*[@id='foo']
```

Comment: It is working perfect. but is there any way to achieve this by LINQ or any entity framework object medel?